# URL Route for all controllers of a folder as an API in MVC .Net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have to define following on all web API.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

How can I define this as default which is in particular folder.

Let's say I have folder **API**. in which I want to set these attributes (or don't want to write) on all controllers of that folder.

How to define this sort of route in .Net core MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto App_Start folder WebApiConfig.cs and put this code there, So it will be applied globally for all the controllers and action methods.
You can invoke this in project like 
http://localhost/API/ControllerName/MethodName?parameters

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithId", "Api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }, new { id = @"\d+" });
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithAction", "Api/{controller}/{action}");
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiGet", "Api/{controller}", new { action = "Get" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) });
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiPost", "Api/{controller}", new { action = "Post" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post) });
```